# How to disable dates in second datetimepicker based on selection in the first one

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I am using moment.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker by eonasdan. I have two datetimepicker in my page. One is for startdate of arrival and the other one is for enddate.

I would like to disable all dates on datetimepicker 2 before selected date on datetimepicker 1.

```
<form id="form" name="form" class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
    <input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" 
/>
    &nbsp;
    <label for="endDate">End Date</label>
    <input id="endDate" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
</form>
```

And the javascript block:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        minDate: moment()
    });
    $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
        maxDate:  moment() 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like below, u can set second date picker value

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({
             showOtherMonths: true,
             selectOtherMonths: true,
             dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
             onSelect: function (selectedDate) {            
                 var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); 
                 $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
             }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working with datepicker.  What do i need to do so it will also work with dateTimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Add property `daysOfWeekDisabled` and pass an `array` containing which days to be disabled, where `0` is Sunday and `6` is Saturday.

Note that you disable `Days` and not `Dates`

If you want to disable all of them:

```
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    maxDate:  moment(),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
});
```

And when the user selects date from the first `datepicker` simply remove the property from the second `datepicker`

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#disabled-days-of-the-week